# Проброс локального порта

Tags: windows, netsh

Необходимо сделать проброс запроса извне на localhost (ip helper запущен, ipv4 и ipv6 разрешены на локальной машине). На роутере порт уже проброшен, переадресуется на

```
192.168.0.204:1234
```

На локальной машине слушается адрес:

```
http://localhost:35843/test
```

Для проброски запроса с 192.168.0.204:1234 на localhost:35843/test делаю следующее:

```bash
netsh interface portproxy add v4tov4 listenaddress=192.168.0.204 listenport=1234 connectaddress=localhost/test connectport=35843
```

В итоге адрес "test" почему-то воспринимается как порт:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что делаю неверно?

Comment: Так ведь на уровне протокола никаких /test не существует, есть только адрес и порт.

Comment: @Yaant, т.е. доменное имя указать невозможно?

Comment: Возможно. localhost написать можно. А localhost/test - это уже не доменное имя. _[connectaddress Указывает IPv6-адрес, к которому необходимо подключиться. Допустимые значения: IP-адрес, имя NetBIOS или DNS-имя компьютера.](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows-server/networking/technologies/netsh/netsh-interface-portproxy#add-v4tov4)_